# Office 365 with SSO, but needs email to be accessed via POP and send mails via SMTP

Tags: smtp, microsoft-office-365, gmail, single-sign-on, pop3

We are moving from Godaddy to Office 365. Many of our staff use Thunderbird and a few use Gmail to read office emails (collection emails via POP).

Office 365 uses SSO by OneLogin to authenticate users. After we move to Office 365 we still want users to be able to:

1. Access Office 365 and outlook web using OneLogin SSO
2. Access email via POP so they can still use Thunderbird or Gmail as their client (I too personally prefer to continue using Gmail)

Now the problem we are facing is that since SSO is enabled, Office 365 doesn't have its own password. But POP and SMTP needs this. How do I configure this? From outlook settings in admin section, we have enabled POP and SMTP access. But there is no option to set a password.

Comment: Thunderbird should just work; you have to select OAuth2 authentication. What problem did you have setting it up?

Comment: Thunderbird works. But some of our staff prefer to use Gmail to fetch our Office 365 mails. There is on OAuth option for Gmail to connect to Office 365